# How do you make content in a website cover the hero image as scrolling down

Tags: image, scroll, css-position

I know this has been a duplicate question but I have tried to make two div with one being the hero image and the other being the content. I wanted the hero image to stay in position when the user scrolls and get covered by the other div but when I try to make the hero image div position fixed the whole image just disappears. I know fixed position gets the element overlapped but when I try to play with z index the image still doesn't show up. Am I doing something wrong?

HTML:

```
    <div class='heroImgContainer'>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.heroImgContainer {
    background-image: url('.png');
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}


.content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the z-index.

```
.heroImgContainer {
background-image: url('.png');
height: 400px;
position: fixed;
z-index: -1;
```

}

You also need to position the content section lower by 400px, so that it does not cover the image.

```
.content {
height: 1000px;
background-color: black;
position: relative;
top: 400px;
```

}

Sample Code Pen: [Static Hero with overlay](https://codepen.io/stromyc/pen/BabLOVK)